# Register file type for app does not work correctly

Tags: android

I am using the following intent filter for my app.

```
<intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.etxt" />
</intent-filter>
```

But to my surprise, the app now wants to open other types too, like apk files. What is my mistake?

Comment: I should add, that I tested with Dropbox. Clicking on an apk file there offers my program and the package installer. Probably the same in any other file manager.

Comment: see my answer and tall me if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. At least, it works for Dropbox now.

```
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file"/>
    <data android:host="*"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/*"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.etxt" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <data android:pathPattern=".\\*.etxt" />
```

not `<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.etxt" />`

and please let me know if it works

Comment: No that still opens anything. Might be that the mimeType is too general?

Comment: yes the mime type says open everything but pathPattern should restrict., can you try to remove the mimetype from the filter, try just with the pathPattern.

Comment: but why you have .etxt is your file ends with .etxt, or maybe it is .txt ?

Comment: Yes the files end with "etxt" (for encrypted text). That is the file format used by Encrypted Notepad. And removing the mime type just stops the filter to be matched. Nothing is opened.

Comment: how about <data android:mimeType="*/*.etxt" /> I do not know if that is allowed but I am very interested if that will work

Comment: It seems that the path pattern is simply ignored. You can write anything there. Maybe the problem is impossible to solve, unless the file has a mime type? Your mime-type does also not work. They do not want discussions in comments here. So better stop with this trial and error thing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3667/discussion-between-luk-and-rene)

Answer (score 0):

I found this

"These attributes are meaningful only if the scheme and host attributes are also specified for 
the filter."

so you should have scheme and host if you want to use android:pathPattern

it is on the official documentation
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

Note this:
If a scheme is not specified for the intent filter, all the other URI attributes are ignored

so you will have to add scheme and host

Answer (score 0):

This has been some time ago, but I still do not have a proper solution. The solution in the answer below works in Dropbox, but will not open the app in Google mail, or in any file manager. And yes, the path pattern is correct.

I tried with mimeType text/* only, nothing else. This will not work, unless you name the files with extension *.txt. I cannot go this way, since in Windows there is a counterpart, which registers *.etxt for the files.

Then I tried with an additional scheme "content". This works for Google mail if I select a general mimeType, but will offer the app, if the user clicks on the new mail icon in the status bar. So it is too general.

In short, I did not find a way to solve this. It seems to depend on the way, the file managers and mail programs form an intent, and this is not predictable. I guess, it is simply an omission in the Android system.