# Android: Download file directly from browser

Tags: android, browser, associations, download

I'm trying to make the android browser download a file of a specific type '.xxx’ say,  so that I can then set an app to be associated with it.

I've successfully done the association part, in that I've made it so that clicking on a file of the right type in an explorer  app loads the appropriate app. I expected this to carry over to the browser so that if I attempted to download a file type .xxx then it would open the app.

This doesn’t happen,  all that happens is that the text contained in the file is displayed in the browser. I've set up a mime type link for this in astro (application/xxxx) but this has made no difference either. It must be possible to do what I want because If I click on a pdf file for instance the browser downloads it and gives me the option to open a pdf reader.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `<intent-filter>` tag within a `<receiver>` tag in your Application Manifest.

How this works is the following:

1. Android broadcasts an intent
2. The system searches a list of applications capable of receiving that intent
3. The system queries the user to select an application to handle that intent
4. The user selects an application, or is defaulted to a pre-specified application
5. The application opens

Take a look at the [receiver element docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) to see more details about how to implement this.

Holler if you need more help.

Thanks

Comment: @Ian, the meta-data may or may not be needed depending on how the application handles the file... the intent may automatically be launched, or the filepath can be passed to the application... this all depends on what the developer specifies.  Meta-data is hard-coded, generally, though, so you want to be careful with it.

Comment: What I want to do is get the built in browser to see a file type as one that it needs to download.

eg, if I have some files shown in the browser and I click on one of them of type pdf then a pdf reader opens. I want this with my .xxx file and my app.

Does putting statements in my app Manifest change the behavior of the built in browser or should that happen when I create the mime type ?

I can get it so that if I open up astro and click on an .xxx file type my app opens.
What I can't do is get the browser to see that file as one that it needs to download instead of just displaying text.

Comment: i think for the browser, you need to add an intent listening for the browser intent.

Comment: I've got slightly further with this. I was originally using a samsung galaxy and this is the device on which i was having trouble. If I try the same thing on an HTC desire z, it works. So it must be something to do with differences between the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Android applications define which 'file types' they support in their respective manifest files. If your app isn't loading when the browser calls it then maybe there is something missing in your manifest? What happens in the simulator?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

All mime you can you for Android :
[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)